# Highlighting Outliers in scatter plot

Tags: python, scatter-plot, outliers

I am using dataset "tips".

Plotting scatter plot with below code

`sns.scatterplot(data=df['total_bill'])`

[image]

I want to show the outliers let's say in this case points which are above 40 on y-axis, in different color or big or is it possible to draw a horizontal like at 40?

Comment: It's definitely possible. What have you considered doing so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using seaborn.scatterplot you can leverage the "hue" parameter to plot groups in different color. For your example the following should work

```
is_outlier = (df['total_bill'] >= 40)
sns.scatterplot(data=df['total_bill'], hue=is_outlier)
```

Comment: Not getting anything on plot. Just the legends only.

Comment: Actually, you need to specifty x and y both. After specifying it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, i did miss that.

Answer (score 0):

With below code desired result achieved.

`sns.scatterplot(data=df, y='total_bill', x=range(0,244), hue='is_outlier')`

[image]

Comment: you're missing the code that sets 'is_outlier' > 40

Comment: That already been taken care off.